# How do you sort column values in pandas to only include certain values?

Tags: python, pandas

Essentially my program finds the person with the most yards per carry, but finds the person with only a couple of attempts.

I'm trying to filter out the rest of the players so that I only get people with above 200 yards so far in the season.

All of the data comes from a CSV file and so it has to be done thru pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

wide_receiver = pd.read_csv('nfl-flex.csv')
wide_receiver['ypc'] =  wide_receiver.reyds / wide_receiver.rec
wr_ypc = wide_receiver[wide_receiver['pos'] == 'WR']['ypc'].max()
yards_leader = wide_receiver.loc[wide_receiver['ypc'] == wr_ypc]
print(yards_leader['name'])
```

I'm not quite sure how to filter out those players with less than 200 yards.

***Output:***

```
{'id': {0: 11706, 1: 11791, 2: 11792, 3: 11793, 4: 11810}, 'name': {0: 'Mark Ingram', 1: 'Rob Gronkowski', 2: 'Marcedes Lewis', 3: 'Jimmy Graham', 4: 'Jared Cook'}, 'fpts': {0: 100.5, 1: 90.8, 2: 26.1, 3: 21.8, 4: 90.1}, 'gp': {0: 11, 1: 6, 2: 12, 3: 9, 4: 11}, 'cmp': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'att': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'payds': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'patd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'int': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'ruatt': {0: 137, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'ruyds': {0: 499, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'rutd': {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'tar': {0: 31, 1: 39, 2: 17, 3: 12, 4: 55}, 'rec': {0: 24, 1: 29, 2: 14, 3: 6, 4: 33}, 'rzatt': {0: 22, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'rztar': {0: 5, 1: 8, 2: 2, 3: 5, 4: 7}, 'reyds': {0: 156, 1: 378, 2: 121, 3: 98, 4: 371}, 'retd': {0: 0, 1: 4, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 3}, 'fuml': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'putd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'krtd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'fumtd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, '2ptpa': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, '2ptru': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, '2ptre': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1}, 'pct': {0: '0.00%', 1: '0.00%', 2: '0.00%', 3: '0.00%', 4: '0.00%'}, 'ruypc': {0: 3.64, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}, 'reypc': {0: 6.5, 1: 13.03, 2: 8.64, 3: 16.33, 4: 11.24}, 'tchs': {0: 161, 1: 29, 2: 14, 3: 6, 4: 33}, 'tyds': {0: 655, 1: 378, 2: 121, 3: 98, 4: 371}, 'team': {0: 'NOS', 1: 'TBB', 2: 'GBP', 3: 'CHI', 4: 'LAC'}, 'pos': {0: 'RB', 1: 'TE', 2: 'TE', 3: 'TE', 4: 'TE'}, 'ypc': {0: 6.5, 1: 13.03448275862069, 2: 8.642857142857142, 3: 16.333333333333332, 4: 11.242424242424242}}
```

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your dataframe by running `print(wide_receiver.head().to_dict())`?

Comment: here's the link to the code and output: https://imgur.com/a/uRSAV2s

Comment: Sorry, I meant a text sample. Will you please copy&paste the output into the question?

Comment: Got it, just put the output into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You filter when you did `yards_leader = wide_receiver.loc[wide_receiver['ypc'] == wr_ypc]`, so now just use that same concept.

```
import pandas as pd

sample_dict = {'id': {0: 11706, 1: 11791, 2: 11792, 3: 11793, 4: 11810}, 'name': {0: 'Mark Ingram', 1: 'Rob Gronkowski', 2: 'Marcedes Lewis', 3: 'Jimmy Graham', 4: 'Jared Cook'}, 'fpts': {0: 100.5, 1: 90.8, 2: 26.1, 3: 21.8, 4: 90.1}, 'gp': {0: 11, 1: 6, 2: 12, 3: 9, 4: 11}, 'cmp': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'att': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'payds': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'patd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'int': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'ruatt': {0: 137, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'ruyds': {0: 499, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'rutd': {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'tar': {0: 31, 1: 39, 2: 17, 3: 12, 4: 55}, 'rec': {0: 24, 1: 29, 2: 14, 3: 6, 4: 33}, 'rzatt': {0: 22, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'rztar': {0: 5, 1: 8, 2: 2, 3: 5, 4: 7}, 'reyds': {0: 156, 1: 378, 2: 121, 3: 98, 4: 371}, 'retd': {0: 0, 1: 4, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 3}, 'fuml': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'putd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'krtd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'fumtd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, '2ptpa': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, '2ptru': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, '2ptre': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1}, 'pct': {0: '0.00%', 1: '0.00%', 2: '0.00%', 3: '0.00%', 4: '0.00%'}, 'ruypc': {0: 3.64, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}, 'reypc': {0: 6.5, 1: 13.03, 2: 8.64, 3: 16.33, 4: 11.24}, 'tchs': {0: 161, 1: 29, 2: 14, 3: 6, 4: 33}, 'tyds': {0: 655, 1: 378, 2: 121, 3: 98, 4: 371}, 'team': {0: 'NOS', 1: 'TBB', 2: 'GBP', 3: 'CHI', 4: 'LAC'}, 'pos': {0: 'RB', 1: 'TE', 2: 'TE', 3: 'TE', 4: 'TE'}, 'ypc': {0: 6.5, 1: 13.03448275862069, 2: 8.642857142857142, 3: 16.333333333333332, 4: 11.242424242424242}}

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)
filtered_sample_df = sample_df[sample_df['reyds'] > 200]
```

**Output:**

```
print(sample_df)
      id            name   fpts  gp  cmp  ...  tchs  tyds  team  pos        ypc
0  11706     Mark Ingram  100.5  11    0  ...   161   655   NOS   RB   6.500000
1  11791  Rob Gronkowski   90.8   6    0  ...    29   378   TBB   TE  13.034483
2  11792  Marcedes Lewis   26.1  12    0  ...    14   121   GBP   TE   8.642857
3  11793    Jimmy Graham   21.8   9    0  ...     6    98   CHI   TE  16.333333
4  11810      Jared Cook   90.1  11    0  ...    33   371   LAC   TE  11.242424

[5 rows x 33 columns]

print(filtered_sample_df)
      id            name  fpts  gp  cmp  ...  tchs  tyds  team  pos        ypc
1  11791  Rob Gronkowski  90.8   6    0  ...    29   378   TBB   TE  13.034483
4  11810      Jared Cook  90.1  11    0  ...    33   371   LAC   TE  11.242424

[2 rows x 33 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked well.

Comment: @outdoors_coder, glad it worked. Be sure then to accept the solution